# C# - UPDATE SET WHERE Query issues (OleDb)

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, oledbcommand

I have a Access 2000 (*.mdb) file which is edited by OleDb Queries.

At the moment I would like to `UPDATE` a table into a database which has only two columns as you can see in the picture below

[image]

*Every column of this database is of type `String`*

This code, thows an `OleDbException`:

```
OleDbConnection con;
OleDbCommand cmd;

private void UpdateExistingRow()
{
    string strProvider = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + path + ";"
    string strSql = "UPDATE OPTIONS SET VAL='C:\\Edo\\Desktop\\Logo.png' WHERE IMP='LogoPath'";
    con = new OleDbConnection(strProvider);
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

It seems simple, I know, but I'm not able to find a solution.
Thank You.

Comment: How can it be? Is it a typo that you miss **`"`** in the end of line 4: `string strSql = "UPDATE OPTIONS SET VAL='C:\\Edo\\Desktop\\Logo.png' WHERE IMP='LogoPath';`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put it in this question!

Comment: @PhamX.Bach I was thinking the same thing. Even the Exception is missing a '  The actual code wouldn't compile if the " was missing, so maybe it's a missing ' instead

Comment: Yes Radlwimmer, @Edoardo Chiabra could you confirm that your code is not missing `'` after `'LogoPath` like that: `'LogoPath";`?

Comment: Yes @PhamX.Bach, I wrote the question wrongly. The code is actually like this: `'LogoPath'"`

Comment: could you debug by add this: `WHERE IMP='LogoPath' and 1=1";` and show the new exception message?

Comment: [Image link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B95a6QqwF2VpNGFXVFo4TW51TGs)
Translation:
"Syntax error ( missing operator) in query ' IMP = ' LogoPath ' and 1 = 1 ' ."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was not as obvious as we initially thought, but I think I found it:
[IMP is a reserved keyword in Access SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845663.aspx) (or more likely: an operator). Strangely though [it doesn't show up in the JET documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321266).

So you need to make sure the DB Engine knows it's a column name by escaping your colum names with `[]`:

```sql
UPDATE [OPTIONS] SET VAL='C:\\Edo\\Desktop\\Logo.png' WHERE [IMP] = 'LogoPath'
```

Comment: I really don't know how to thank you.
Perfect and detailed answer.